# Open Pbix file with ODBC connection in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: visual-studio, azure, odbc, powerbi, azure-analysis-services

I want to add a new model in Azure Analysis Services by using a Pbix file (to afterwards retrieve the data model of that pbix file in Visual Studio). I have no problems when there are flat files as sources of my pbix, but I can't do it with an ODBC connection. Here is my error message `Model with name ModelName contains unsupported datasource Odbc/authentication=LDAP;`

Do you have any idea of how could I do it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis Services and PowerBI do not support the same set of connectors.

See [Analysis Services supported sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource)

and [PowerBI supported sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-sources)

To do what you are after, you can only use the services common to both.

Comment: I agree but I see that Azure support ODBC and this is why I don't understand the error message although I'm using an ODBC connection string